# Looping through elements in a sequence

Tags: lists, expl3, loops

In a follow up of [Highlighting words only the first time they appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268250/highlighting-words-only-the-first-time-they-appear) it was suggested to use `\seq_use:Nn` to display the content of a sequence. It works really nice but it concatenates the items with a given separator (like `join` in Python). Is there a way to loop through the elements and do something with each of them?

Comment: Yes, of course: `\seq_map_inline:Nn` and `\seq_map_function:NN`

Comment: I've added an expl3 tag as that seems to be what you're asking about. Basic LateX (non expl3) strategies would include using macros with counters and conditionals, making csname arrays, or using packages like pgf or datatool.

Comment: @Werner Only tangentially

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=seq_map_inline%3ANn lists 220 entries.